# How did the Upside-Down have electricity?

Tags: stranger-things

In Season 2, Episode 2, Will has a vision or episode in the Upside-Down. When he enters the Upside-Down, he sees a row of eerily glowing blue streetlamps.

[image]

I don’t believe these were there before, and to the best of my knowledge the Upside-Down doesn’t have a working power infrastructure. So how and why did these lamps have electricity? Was it the doing of the DoE scientists? The Mind Flayer?

Comment: Might not be electricity eh. Might just be a ghostly light.

Comment: In one scene (not sure which episode, I think it was 2 but it might have been 3) didn't they send a guy through to repair what appeared to be some kind of fuse? He was definitely in the Upside Down, he burned his way through and there were the usual floating particles all around. If there are fuses then there's electricity, so maybe the scientists have rigged up lighting to help with moving around over there, or it's some kind of data-recording equipment?

Comment: Don't know how, see my comment below, infrastructure is there but that alone doesn't explain electricity being available, and Hawkins Lab hasn't been connected to it in over a year by Season 4, but Dustin still plugs Eddie's amp in to an outlet in the upside down so he can play Master of Puppets with no issues...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not just this one scene, the Upside Down always has electricity. 
Here are a few other scenes where you can see it.

[image]
[image]

As to how exactly it works, there is no universe explanation (yet). But I'd speculate that since the Upside Down is just a mirror of our world (albeit a twisted one), with the same buildings as us, it also contains the infrastructure needed for electricity.

Comment: I don't believe it *is* a mirror, though. I think that's a red herring. I think it's an alternate timeline.

Comment: But more to the point: the lighting wasn't there last season.

Comment: I think the upside down is waking up to their presence.

Comment: @Adamant why do you think it's an alternate timeline? Any clues regarding that on the show?

Comment: It looks bioluminescent to me.

Comment: Season 4 has revealed that, in fact, the infrastructure would be there. So that part is correct. However, it still doesn't make sense. It takes more than infrastructure, you have to have fuel coming in to power the generators, and there are no people in the upside down extract it from the ground or to maintain the equipment...

Answer (score 3):

### Likely due to the efforts of the lab

It’s quite likely that the DoE lab
is ensuring that the infrastructure is maintained. In the second episode, they send a soldier in to fix something:

> DOCTOR OWENS: How’s it looking out there, cowboy?
>
> SOLDIER: Uh, you know, Doc. The usual. Nice and nasty with a chance of
> radioactivity. Oh, yeah, it’s barbecued all right. Anyone hungry?
>
> SCIENTIST: And we’re back on!
>
> <sub>*Stranger Things*, “Trick or Treat, Freak”</sub>

And then a bunch of indicator lights go on.

The thing they’re fixing definitely seems to be some sort of power box.

[image]

The clear implication is that the lab has some power infrastructure set up. It had gone out, which means that it was running before. It was likely set up after Owens took over (which is why, I think, we didn’t see any lights there last season).

Presumably they’re taking advantage of pre-existing infrastructure in the Upside-Down, not running power in. As to why that infrastructure exists in the first place, it’s uncertain, but [see my theory.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172997/51379)

Comment: I think the thing they're fixing is just a bunch of remote sensors that they're using to investigate the Upside-Down, like a planetary lander but wired.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - It’s certainly connected to some sensors, but I think they’re running from the power grid.

Comment: Doesn't it have wires running back into the lab?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - I think they’re using to power their sensors, too. They’ve likely taken advantage of the pre-existing power network. But given that we didn’t see any lights last season, I’m inclined to think that this is why the power’s on. It sure looks like a power box, too.